# Access to path is denied

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am working in SharePoint 2010. My requirement is to create folder inside SharePoint layouts and create a file inside that folder. Also I need to access the file for a current logged in user.

Layouts-> Files-->file1.txt.

Please check out the code below.

```
String tempFilePath = SPUtility.GetGenericSetupPath(String.Empty) + "TEMPLATE\\LAYOUTS\\Files";         

DirectorySecurity securityRules = new DirectorySecurity();
securityRules.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(strUserName, FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));
bool IsExist = System.IO.Directory.Exists(v);

if (!IsExist )
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(tempFilePath ,securityRules);
```

In the code above if the strUserName is Administrator then the directory(Files) will be created successfully. But for other than Administrator account CreateDirectory will fail( access to the path denied). Can anyone tell me how can I create the folder in sharpoint layouts for any user with full permission?

Answer (score 0):

Use SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges to make your code for the other logged in users as well.

Check Below given link for the example

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsecurity.runwithelevatedprivileges.aspx